# Range.PastSpecial(...) is failing

Tags: c#, excel-automation

I am using Interop.Excel for doing this task.
I am trying to copy a range of cells from one workbook's sheet and paste it into a separate workbook's sheet, but I want to keep the formatting from the source sheet and paste it into the destination sheet. I found the PasteSpecial, and tried to use that, but when I try it, I get an unhelpful exception message : "PastSpecial methos of Range class failed", which has an HResult of -2146827284. Could not find anything via google, so here I am to hopefully get some help...

I use the code below to try this. I also did try using Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll as the initial parameter to the PastSpecial method, and that did actually Paste the data into the destination sheet, and so I thought great, this works, but when I looked closer, I could see, very fiently, what looked like extra gridlines, and when I clicked on the pasted data, it was a whole object which could be moved around, much like an image pasted in that can be moved. This of course is not what I wanted. The idea is that I need to preserve the formatting and the border styles and the colors used.

Many thanks for reading - apologies if my formatting in the post has messed up.

```
Excel.Range rng6 = sht6.Cells.get_Range("A1", "O55"); 
Excel.Range rng1 = sht.get_Range("A" + rowStart6.ToString(), "O" + rowEnd6.ToString());
rng6.Copy(mis);
/** Fails here at PasteSpecial**/
rng1.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

Comment: I think the reason is difference between the two ranges form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. the simplest answer to this was to just use a single argument : rng1.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats);